# spark app socket communication between container on docker spark cluster

Tags: docker, apache-spark, spark-streaming

So I have a Spark cluster running in Docker using Docker Compose. I'm using [docker-spark](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark) images.

Then i add 2 more containers, 1 is behave as server (plain python) and 1 as client (spark streaming app). They both run on the same network.

For server (plain python) i have something like

```
import socket
s.bind(('', 9009))
    s.listen(1)
    print("Waiting for TCP connection...")
    while True:
        # Do and send stuff
```

And for my client (spark app) i have something like

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("MyApp")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
ssc.checkpoint("my_checkpoint")
# read data from port 9009
dataStream = ssc.socketTextStream(PORT, 9009)
# What's PORT's value?
```

So what is PORT's value? is it the IP Adress value from docker inspect of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i found that i can use the IP of the container, as long as all my containers are on the same network.
So i check the IP by running

```
docker inspect <container_id>
```

and check the IP, and use that as host for my socket

Edit:
I know it's kinda late, but i just found out that i can actually use the container's name as long as they're in the same network

More edit:

i made changes in docker-compose like:

```sh
container-1:
    image: image-1
    container_name: container-1
    networks:
      - network-1
container-2:
    image: image-2
    container_name: container-2
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - network-1
```

and then in my script (container 2):

```py
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("MyApp")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
ssc.checkpoint("my_checkpoint")
# read data from port 9009

dataStream = ssc.socketTextStream("container-1", 9009) #Put container's name here
```

I also expose the socket port in Dockerfile, I don't know if that have effect or not

Comment: Can you check if using service name alone would work too? I'm curious (and think it's more flexible as IPs can change every restart).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski by theory it would work as well, I'll give it a try and inform it here